# Why doesn't the print method take the linkedlist object?

Tags: java, printing, linked-list

I have a project where I have to create and use a print linked list method. I am able to print using a basic for loop, but receive a error: linkedlist Name<> cannot be converted to Name[] when trying to use the print method. I used a similar approach an array and it worked fine.

```
public class Scratch {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //Animal type(string) and age(int)
        Animal animal1 = new Animal("dog",7);
        Animal animal2 = new Animal("cat",4);
        Animal animal3 = new Animal("direwolf",30);
        
        //Name includes Animal using constructor
        Name name1 = new Name("Cujo",animal1);
        Name name2 = new Name("Pete",animal2);
        Name name3 = new Name("Ghost",animal3);      
        
        //Must create linkedlist
        LinkedList<Name> name = new LinkedList<Name>();
        name.add(name1);
        name.add(name2);
        name.add(name3);
        System.out.println();
        
        //Prints Fine
        for(Name n : name){
            System.out.println(n);
            System.out.println();
        }

        //Doesn't print: Error linkedlist Name<> cannot be converted to Name[]
        printLL(name);  
    }
    
    private static void printLL(Name[] pll){
        for (Name e : pll){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: A linked list (`LinkedList<Name>`) is not an array (`Name[]`).

Comment: Also, your method is called `printLL()` while you call `printLinkedList()`?

Comment: Really? I get "Symbol not found: `printLinkedList`"

Comment: Why do you believe that a `LinkedList<Name>` value could be assigned to a parameter of type `Name[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

printLL takes an array of Name as a parameter. Why would you expect that to work if you passed it a linkedList.

Try:

```
private static void printLL(List<Name> pll){
    for (Name e : pll){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I shouldn't have expected it to work, but it is clear I didn't understand all the nuances of what was going on with the the array print method. Seems like these projects are designed to help people connect pieces they've never worked with before. thx